# How to build Flutter for iOS on PC using VMware

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a small app (make with Flutter) that has successfully built on android with Android Studio, now I want to build for iOS, I have copied the project to the macOS on VMware (i am using a PC) and when I build with Xcode I get the error:

/ bin / sh: D: \ ... \ flutter / packages / flutter_tools / bin / xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory

I think the virtual machine can not read the path to the Flutter SDK because it's on the PC, so how can I fix this?

UPDATE:

Currently, my solution is:

- Install Flutter and Android Studio on MacOs, keep check `flutter doctor -v` and install the missing
- Create a Flutter project with Android Studio

=> Now I can build for both Android & iOS in Android Studio without error

Comment: What does `flutter doctor -v` show on the Mac VM?

Comment: it's show: -bash: flutter: command not found

Comment: You need to install flutter in the macos instance. You will end up with two separate copies, Windows and macos. Consider putting your source code in git and cloning two copies one in each os to handle the differences in line endings.

Comment: After install flutter and set PATH, now it can show Flutter detail info from `flutter doctor -v`, but i'm still got same error. I found out all path in file "Generated.xcconfig" maybe wrong:
FLUTTER_ROOT=D:\ToolAndLib\flutter
FLUTTER_APPLICATION_PATH=D:\ProjectWorking\Flutter\sh_demo
FLUTTER_TARGET=lib/main.dart
FLUTTER_BUILD_MODE=debug
FLUTTER_BUILD_DIR=build
SYMROOT=${SOURCE_ROOT}/../build\ios
FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR=D:\ToolAndLib\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\ios
How to get the right PATH, i'm new to MacOS

Comment: Start by creating yourself a new project in macos, and check that that runs. It helps everyone if you keep editing the question as you refine it. So now you should add the output of doctor to the question to prove that you've tried that.

Comment: I created a new project on MacOS and it run fine, then i replace code from my project, it also run fine but i got an error from output of Xcode:
`No static method 'only' declared in class 'EdgeInsets'`
and the widget did not show

Comment: That's good that you got something going under MacOS. Did you change more than the contents of `/lib`? Try more gradual chages to see where it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

While Xcode can compile the iOS build generated in your Flutter app, the recently copied project needs to be imported to Android Studio to ensure that all things are set correctly. Also, the iOS build from Flutter can be run from Android Studio if you're on macOS https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive#run-the-app

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VMWare for it. Consider using Hackintosh OS to run on a PC.

Hackintosh requires a separated VGA card to run (onboard VGA card does not work). And, only some versions of the Hackintosh can be installed.

After installing it on your normal PC, you can run your PC as a MAC OS. You can build your own app for both Android & iOS from now on.

Google for more details.